# How can wordpress function receive function as argument?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

How can the WP function `add_action` receive another function as its argument? I know this by itself is not possible in php (to have custom functions receive other functions as arguments). I deliberately broke some code and found that there is actually a native php function `call_user_fun_array` beneath this (i think),

but how did they make it so that their own function can have a function as its argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a native PHP function **call_user_func()** Take a look on this pretty simple example.

```
function caller($custom_func){
return call_user_func($custom_func);
}
function make_echo(){
echo 'something';
}

caller('make_echo');
```